# refresh bash tab completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have a script for auto-completing my ssh-hosts. If I change my `~/.ssh/config` the auto-completion is not updated automatically, though. This does not surprise me. In a new shell, the new entry is picked up and usable, of course.

How do I manually trigger a refresh of the completion in bash?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
exec bash
```

this will do the trick...

Comment: neat, that replaces the current shell... In a way, that like opening a new shell, but still nice.

Answer (score 10):

See [reload bash completion functions file](https://gist.github.com/NapoleonWils0n/4052774)

```
. /etc/bash_completion.d/filename
```

(adapt `/etc` depending on where your bash_completion scripts are deployed, replace `filename` by the appropriate script)

Comment: Usually `. /etc/bash_completion` is my solution.

Comment: Do any of you know why?

Comment: @JoelBerger I could hazard a guess... the files mentioned here are themselves bash scripts, so by running them in this way, you're resetting the bash settings just as you would running any bash script.  Running /etc/bash_completion is likely best if available, as it reruns all the completion scripts.